# Docker containers deployment

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

When deploying a docker based micro-services app using docker-compose, should you build images using Dockerfiles or building images, loading them then using Docker images?

Comment: You could do a lot to clarify what you're asking here. At the moment I'm entirely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either/or.  I prefer to build images separately and then deploy them separately with docker-compose.  This is my preference since I tend to use a CI/CD process and system:

1. Create a build pipeline to compile my code
2. In the same build pipeline - at the end add a step to build the container image with "build -t name:tagname ."
3. In the deployment/release pipeline make use of a docker-compose file to bring up my stack of containers with "docker-compose -f docker-compile-file.yml up -d"

I like to break up my activity into separate steps so it gives me flexibility to execute individual steps when I want.  It's up to you and how you work and what situation you are in.  Visual Studio uses a docker-compose file to build and deploy together.